# Im trying to calculate uptime in Grafana based on the successful responses from Prometheus blackbox exporter

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I've tried counting the number of probe_success and multiplying it by the probe interval trying to get uptime in seconds and setting the value type to the total. the issue is the minimum step changes as the time frame changes not giving us a correct reading and nulling this option. What we are actually trying to do is get the percentage uptime based on successful probes in the time frame set for the dashboard. We are using singlestat to show the percentage

```
(probe_success{instance="www.google.com:443",job="clienttest"})*15
```

We tried dividing the value by an exporter its self to try to get a percentage that would also scale to no avail.

```
sum(probe_success{instance="www.google.com:443",job="clienttest"}) / sum(probe_success{instance="self",job="clienttest"}) *100
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a singlestat panel what you want to do is use just `probe_success{instance="www.google.com:443",job="clienttest"}` as the expression, and under options make sure you are using the Average aggregation.

On the PromQL side you can also do `avg_over_time(probe_success[1h])`, see [this blog post](https://www.robustperception.io/what-percentage-of-time-is-my-service-down-for/).

Comment: Thank you so much, This seams so obvious now but would have never guessed it.

Comment: Shot out of left field how would one get a value in seconds for this?

Comment: Multiply by 3600.

Comment: what if you have multiple endpoints that make up a service uptime?  example www.google.com:443 and mail.google.com:443 then would you use something like sum(avg_over_time(probe_success{instance=~".*google.com:443"}[1h]) * 100) / 2 ?