# Calculating availability in Prometheus based on response value

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus

I am trying to calculate the availability of elasticsearch using prometheus. One of the jobs that runs get the cluster status as a value, being either 0, 1 or 2 where anything above 1 is considered unavailable.
Using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156704/im-trying-to-calculate-uptime-in-grafana-based-on-the-successful-responses-from) does not work due to all the jobs succeeding and so the query has to do something along the lines of:

```
avg_over_time(es_cluster_status{cluster="name", instance="my_es"}>1[24h])
```

This does however not work due to the `>1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus does not support filtering samples in range vectors, the `>1` would only work for filtering vectors based on their instant value.

The simplest workaround is for you to define a recorded rule that would behave just like the `up` metric does (`0` when your target is down, `1` otherwise). Something like `es_cluster_status{cluster="name", instance="my_es"} <= 1`. Then you could apply `avg_over_time()` on that metric and get the availability over any given range.